# Extract parameter values from url android

Tags: java, android

```
public static Hashtable parseUrlString(String url) {
    Hashtable parameter = new Hashtable();
    List<NameValuePair> params = null;
    try {
        params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");
        for (NameValuePair param : params) {
            if (param.getName() != null && param.getValue() != null)
                parameter.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return parameter;
}
```

The above method works for me to extract parameter name with value to a hashtable but in Api 21+ the NameValuePair and **URLEncodedUtils** is deprecated so what is the best way that I can replace this method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Android, you should never use [URLEncodedUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) which is now deprecated. A good alternative is to use the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class instead: retrieve the query parameter keys using `getQueryParameterNames()` then iterate on them and retrieve each value using `getQueryParameter()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the android.net.Uri.

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
```

It has getQueryParameterNames() and uri.getQueryParameter(parameterNameString);

Answer (score 9):

Already answered but here is the method written out

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getQueryString(String url) {
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(url);

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String paramName : uri.getQueryParameterNames()) {
        if (paramName != null) {
            String paramValue = uri.getQueryParameter(paramName);
            if (paramValue != null) {
                map.put(paramName, paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

try:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(yourStrUrl);
 String paramValue = uri.getQueryParameter("yourParam");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ContentValues

```
for (ContentValues param : params) {
            if (param.getName() != null && param.getValue() != null)
                parameter.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response there is one more problem for me URLEncodedUtils also deprecated :(